# Set of finite and infinite $0$-$1$ sequences countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the set of all finite sequences of letters of Latin alphabet countable/uncountable? How to prove either?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29599/is-the-set-of-all-finite-sequences-of-letters-of-latin-alphabet-countable-uncoun)
>   [Is the set of all strings with countably infinite length bijective to $\[0,1\]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65988/is-the-set-of-all-strings-with-countably-infinite-length-bijective-to-0-1)

I'm trying to prove that a set of a finite sequences of $0,1$ (let's call it $A$) is countable infinite, whereas a set of infinite sequences of $0,1$ (call it $B$) equipotent to $P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable infinite.

So far I tried showing that the number of sequences possible in A is $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \ 2^i$. Not sure how to continue from here, if this is even the right direction.

Comment: I also tried finding some bijective function, but to no avail

Comment: Use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable for the first part. For the other, see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86650/proof-that-the-power-set-of-mathbbn-is-uncountable-and-that-the-compositio/86661#86661

Comment: The second part can be understood as a special case of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84180/finding-a-correspondence-between-two-sets/

Comment: For the first, consider the map that sends the sequence $a_0,\ldots,a_N$ to $2^{N+1}+a_N2^N + \cdots + a_02^0$. Prove that this is one-to-one. Then prove the set is infinite.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [65988](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65988/), [61926](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61926/), and [29599](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29599/) put together.

Comment: I voted to close it as a duplicate of [29599](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29599/). Since that question does not cover all parts of this one, I recommend that future voters choose other questions like [61926](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61926/) or [65988](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65988/).

Answer (score 0):

I'll do the first part:

For each positive integer $n$, let $A_n$ be the set of sequences of 0's and 1's of length $n$.
Then $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

Moreover, each $A_n$ is finite. In fact $|A_n|=2^n$. Since a countable union of countable sets is countable, it follows that $A$ is countable.

Now the sequence $\underbrace{0\ 0\ 0\ \cdots\ 0 }_{n-\rm terms}\ 1$ is in $A$ for each positive integer $n$. Thus, $A$ is infinite (and so, countably infinite).

Answer (score 0):

B is a standard application of Cantor's diagonal argument, though the obvious bijection is far more enlightening.